# Search and Replace Filter in Google Analytics

Tags: regex, string, search, replace, google-analytics

I'm using filters to consolidate hits to URLS with different variables , into one URL

so:

```
example.com/abc/123 - 1 hit
example.com/abc/345 - 1 hit
```

will aggregate consolidate to:

```
example.come/abc/ - 2 hits
```

I'm using the SEARCH and REPLACE filter like this :

```
Search string : /abc/.* 
Replace string : /abc/
```

When I verify this filter, it says no data would be changed. When I change the config to

Search string : `/abc/.*` 
Replace string : `/`

It reports a major change. It seems the replace string is not right. I basically want to strip the dynamic portion of the URL by replacing any hit that has a dynamic portion with a URL that only has a static portion.

Answer (score 0):

It should work the way you've indicated, but just in case, here's the setup.

Set the Filter Field to "Request URI", and then in the search field use `/abc/.*`, and in the replace field use `/abc/`.

Check with the Real-time report, in the Contents report, and also make sure you are doing this in a test view first so that you don't accidentally apply it to your production data.